# I can't distribute own package

Tags: python, django, pypi

A month ago I made own [django widget](https://github.com/abbasovalex/django-SplitJSONWidget-form) for a form field. Today it registered [into PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-split-json-widget) by me:

`python setup.py register`

I use `pip` and right off checked it:

> ```
> $ pip search django-split-json-widget
> django-split-json-widget  - Provides a widget that renders JSON data as separate, editable inputs.
> ```

but I can't install my widget:

> ```
> $ pip install django-split-json-widget
> Downloading/unpacking django-split-json-widget
>   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-split-json-widget
> No distributions at all found for django-split-json-widget
> Storing complete log in /Users/apple/.pip/pip.log
>
> $ pip freeze
> Django==1.5.1
> Pygments==1.6
> chromelogger==0.3.0
> distribute==0.6.40
> ipython==0.13.2
> jsonpickle==0.4.0
> psycopg2==2.5
> pudb==2013.1
> requests==1.2.0
> urwid==1.1.1
> wsgiref==0.1.2
> ```

Anybody can help me understand it and solve these causes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only registered your package, but did not *upload* anything.

Run `python setup.py sdist upload` to do so; for a pure python package a source distribution is all you need.

You may want to read the [PyPI howto](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/packageindex.html) for more details.

Comment: Can you answer, `sdist` is name package or command of the setup.py?

Comment: Question is canceled, I saw http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html But remote server return me response `Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information
`

Comment: Which means you didn't add your username and password to your `.pypirc` file. See the Howto I linked to. *The upload command uses the username, password, and repository URL from the $HOME/.pypirc file (see section The .pypirc file for more on this file).*

Comment: It seems procedure had been changed

Comment: Now I am using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine such as `python setup.py sdist` then `twine upload dist/*`

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander: twine is absolutely better, highly recommended.